# How can I delete Lunece.net DeleteDocuments?

Tags: lucene.net

This is my T-SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM Table 
WHERE Id = 10000 AND Locale = N'en-US'
```

How can I convert this T-SQL query to Lucene.net `DeleteDocuments`?

This Lucene.net statement doesn't work.

```
Document document = CreateLocationDocument(region);
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery query = new Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery();

var queryParser1 = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Id", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
var queryParser2 = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Locale", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));

query.Add(queryParser1.Parse(region1.id.ToString()), Lucene.Net.Search.Occur.SHOULD);
query.Add(queryParser2.Parse(region1.languageCode), Lucene.Net.Search.Occur.SHOULD);

indexWriter.DeleteDocuments(query);
```

This sentence is OR query.

I need AND query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use MultiFieldQueryParser
MultiFiendQueryParser has 2 Option 
AND_OPERATOR and OR_OPERATOR.

I can use MultiFieldQueryParser with AND_OPERATOR
You can See this statement

```
Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "language_code", "keyword" }, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
queryParser.DefaultOperator = MultiFieldQueryParser.AND_OPERATOR;
queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
Lucene.Net.Search.Query query = queryParser.Parse(String.Format(@"(language_code:{0} keyword:{1}*)", locationRQ.Language, locationRQ.Query));
```